# ubuntu 12.10 disk partition after installation

Tags: 12.10, disk-utility, disk-management

i bought a laptop with 500 GB hard disk and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it.

During installation it gave me an option to make drives after installing (or something like that) and skipped the core step of making drives and now i can see whole 500GB under Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm unable to make separate drives.

Please help..what can be done now.

I may only use Ubuntu and willing to make drives to store data on them so that there is less burden on the main drive and my system can run fast -- am i right in thinking so?

Thanks in advance....:D

Answer (score 0):

Boot from LiveCD and use GParted.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! While this may answer the question, it is better to include some more detailed information about how to proceed. For more information, see [How to Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-answer).